# Calculating price following different interval of date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm trying to develop a booking system for hotel.
in my search form i've two datepicker (date departure and date arrival), and the destination.
I've a problem with date, in my database i've two tables "prices" and "season" that can be joined with jointure via the id of season .

structure of tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `prix_single` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `prix_double` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `prix_triple` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `idseason` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `idhotel` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=41 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `season` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `begin_date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `end_date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `idhotel` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

for exemple for season a i've the periode of
 1 January to 28 of February (100 $ the night per person)
 1 March to 28 of April (120 $ the night per person)

if my client select the period [26 February to 3 March] how can I calculate it with SQL?
i've tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM season, prices
WHERE season.id=prices.season
and (season.begin_season BETWEEN 2012/02/26 AND 2012/03/03 OR season.fin_season BETWEEN 2012/02/26 AND 2012/03/03)
```

it didn't works for me, it's return to me empty result, i've in my Database two seasons

```
id  begin_season    end_season  idhotel
32  10/07/2012  28/09/2012  52
35  29/09/2012  29/10/2012  52
```

How can i do this?
Thanks a lot!

Edit:
i've changed my tables and my query like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `season` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `begin_season` date NOT NULL,
  `end_season` date NOT NULL,
  `idhotel` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 

INSERT INTO `season` (`id`, `begin_season`, `end_season`, `idhotel`) VALUES
(32, '2012-08-09', '2012-09-09', '52'),
(35, '2012-09-10', '2012-10-30', '52');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `price_single` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `price_double` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `price_triple` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `idseason` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `idhotel` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

INSERT INTO `prices` (`id`, `price_single`, `price_double`, `price_triple`, `idseason`, `idhotel`) VALUES
(31, '10', '20', '30', 32, 52),
(32, '20', '40', '60', 35, 52),

SELECT * FROM season, prices WHERE season.id=prices.idseason and (season.begin_season BETWEEN '2012-09-30' AND '2012-10-27' OR season.end_season BETWEEN '2012-09-30' AND '2012-10-27')
```

My result is empty.

Comment: How is `season.debut_season` not giving you an error? You don't have any such column (unless you forgot to translate that part from french, but did the rest) in your table. There is also no prices.season column either!

Comment: yes it is, i forgot translating it :) i'm sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your begin_date and end_date something other than varchar.  Perhaps a timestamp or an integer representing unix time.

Answer (score 0):

Your `season` table is not set up properly.

`begin_date` and `end_date` are `varchar(255)`... not `date` or `datetime` or `timestamp`

So you cannot use "BETWEEN".  Convert them to date/datetime/timestamp and then you can use all the functionality you want (>,<,BETWEEN, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are formatting your dates incorrectly. The format for dates is

`The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.`

as per documentation here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Does changing that do anything?

EDIT:

Oh, you are not even using DATE as the type. You should do that.

Comment: well, i've changed the type of my date to Datetime, end convert them to YYYY-MMM-DD format
after that i've changed my request : SELECT *
FROM season, prices
WHERE season.id=prix.season
and (season.debut_season BETWEEN '2012-09-30' AND '2012-10-27' OR season.end_season BETWEEN '2012-09-30' AND '2012-10-27')

i've two error, but i' think it linked with my hoster:
import.php: Missing parameter: import_type
import.php: Missing parameter: format
do you think that my request is ok?
thanks a lot!

Comment: Unless you are using times, I would recommend using Date, not Datetime. I think that query should work though.

Comment: i've changed the format to date, my data base contain the following values of date : 2012-08-09 2012-09-09, 2012-09-10 2012-10-30
i've exécuted the same query , i've the same error (mport.php: Missing parameter: import_type import.php: Missing parameter: format)
i think that all is ok following your advice, i'll try to contact my hoster to see if these error are linked with! 
Many thanks!
Edit: now it work, it seems to be a cache problem, my query return to me an empty result :/

Comment: now it works, it seems to be a cache problem, there is no error in my query but it return to me an empty result :/

Comment: Post your new query AND the tables you are querying.